# What's wrong with my SQL string? I can't seems to list all the value from a table to a ListView

Tags: c#, sql, listview, loops

I have 2 tables with relationships, I would like to grab First Name and Last Name from table Patient using the foreign key in MedicalHistory table but it just displays nothing?

```
try
{
    string strPatients = "SELECT patientID FROM MEDICALHISTORY";
    SqlCommand cmdPatient = new SqlCommand(strPatients, connection);

    string strMedicalPatients = "SELECT pFirstName, pLastName FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID= ('" + strConnectionString + "')";
    SqlCommand cmdPatientHistory = new SqlCommand(strMedicalPatients, connection);

    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader readPatients = cmdPatientHistory.ExecuteReader();

    while (readPatients.Read())
    {
        ListViewItem allPatients = new ListViewItem(readPatients["pFirstName"].ToString());
        allPatients.SubItems.Add(readPatients["pLastName"].ToString());

        lsMedicalHistory.Items.Add(allPatients);
    }
    readPatients.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where is `strConnectionString` declared?

Comment: above the try-catch.  When I try to get the patientID alone from only 1 table, it works

Comment: WHAT is `strConnectionString`? - From it's naming, it looks like it could be a database connection string... and you are using that in you SQL Command string to get the patient name `...WHERE patientID= ('" + strConnectionString + "')";`... Is there some sort of variable holding the `patient ID` that should be being used?

Comment: What does `strConnectionString` contain? This variable name suggests something different than a query. Did you already try to debug and inspect what `strMedicalPatients` looks like at runtime? Did you try to run this query inside SQL Management Studio to see what results it retrieves from the database?

Comment: string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HConnection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString);

Comment: Well, you are using `strConnectionString` in your WHERE statement which will obviously result in no data..

Comment: ANother option is to run a sinlge SELECT and use SQL Join to retrieve the name against the hostory item on the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the connection first, then get the patient ID from the Medical History Table, then use that to get the data from the Patients Table. In the code below (untested by the way) the `using` will automatically clean up resources once they're of no further need.

Also, the `finally` section assumed the connection opened, and should be put in its own try-finally, inside the the try-catch.

```
try
{
    connection.Open();
    try
    {

        string strPatients = "     SELECT h.patientID, 
                                          p.pFirstName,
                                          p.pLastName  
                                     FROM MEDICALHISTORY h 
                                LEFT JOIN PATIENT p ON p.patientID = h.patientID 
                                LEFT JOIN ILLNESS i ON i.illnessid = h.illnessID";
        using (SqlCommand cmdPatient = new SqlCommand(strPatients, connection))
        {
            using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmdPatient.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int patientID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["patientID"]);
                    string pFName = Convert.ToString(rdr["pFirstName"]);
                    string pSName = Convert.ToString(rdr["pLastName"]);
                    string pIllness =Convert.ToString(rdr["IllnessDesc"]);


                    // Do stuff with data
               }
           }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
}
```

Comment: It works but it displays only 1 row of patient.  There should be 3 rows with different Patients.

Comment: As you can only had a single SQL reader open at any one time, I would recommend joining the tables in the SELECT statement

Comment: Have updated the answer to JOIN the tables and get each row from MEDICALHISTORY showing the patient name with it. If you want more assistance, then provate message me

Comment: How would you achieve that?  Anyway let's say if there's more than 2 relationships. i.e. I have a another column called Illness in the MedicalHistory table which pointed to a table called Illness.  So I would just continue repeating the JOIN?

Comment: Not knowing the entire data model, its hard for me to say... I've assumed the a Patient has many MedicalHistory records, but what is the relationship of Illness to either of the other... If the Illness is a lookup to the patients problem in this medicalhistory record, then yes you can join them... and I've changed the code to show this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46640/discussion-between-chris-hammond-and-user3195396)